# c++ ThreadProc not Invoked inspite of CreateThread Succeeding

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, deadlock, winsock2

I have an application which uses both TCP ( Winsock API ) and HTTP ( WININET API ) sockets . It's a multi-threaded application and i have a case where when there is a network failure i invoke a Reconnect Thread ( has a while loop , sleeps for few seconds though , each for tcp reconnect & http reconnect - basically attempt socket connection) . When both tcp reconnect thread & http reconnect thread runs after a certain period tcp reconnect thread arrives at this line :

TCP Reconnect Thread :

```
    DWORD WINAPI MyThreadProc ( LPVOID lParam )
    {
       printf ( "In MyThreadProc" ) ;
       // Code
       return 1 ;
    }

    hSampleHandle = CreateThread ( 0 , 0 (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyThreadProc, this , 0 , &threadId ) ;
```

HTTP Reconnect thread :

```
     DWORD WINAPI MyHttpThreadProc ( LPVOID lParam )
     {
       printf ( "In HTTP Reconnect" ) ;
       // Code
       return 1 ;
     }

     hHttpReq = CreateThread ( 0 , 0 , MyHttpThreadProc , this , 0 , &ThreadId ) ;
```

I check for hSampleHandle return value and it isnt NULL also i get a threadId . But MyThreadProc isn't getting invoked . I then do WaitForSingleObject which timesout . I really want to know what is the reason for this behaviour ?

Update : 
1)Having commented out the code in MyHttpThreadProc i couldnt reproduce the bug . So it is very clear that some resource is shared between winsock & wininet implementation that causes this strange behaviour .

2)I tried freezing the HTTP reconnect thread ( From ThreadWindow in Visual Studio 2012 ) and it the TCP reconnect thread worked fine . This led to the follwng probes :

P.S : 1) There are no shared resources between these two at application level .

2) I suspected a deadlock and continued to debug in windbg ( user-mode deadlocks ) which showed 9 critical sections but all 9 sections having lockcount value to be NOT LOCKED .

3) My another suspect is the use of WINSOCK & WININET together. I know both of them uses mswsock.dll and could it be a loaderlock that causes a kernel deadlock ? On issuing !kdexts.locks i face some errors so i havent dig deep on that .

4) Does this comes under a thread freeze category ? Can someone explain on this behaviour .

5) This http://www.cpptalk.net/threadproc-does-not-run-when-createthread-is-called-within-vt7735.html isn't useful here since i dont use a seperate dll .

Comment: I would first fix the reason for having to cast the function pointer - that's usually a sign of a bug. And without more information we can't really help you otherwise, my crystal ball just broke this morning. Create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Please post declaration of `MyThreadProc`.

Comment: Show more code. The only problem I see is an unnecessary (and dangerous) cast. You don't cause kernel deadlocks from userspace. In windbg, issue ~ command to list all threads. Can you see yours? Print its stack with ~nk, where n is the thread number.

Comment: you have a missing comma here: `CreateThread ( 0 , 0 (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyThreadProc,`

Comment: @Voo : You are right . Unnecessary casting . I removed it but the problem still exists .

Comment: Well, 'this' is shared - you explicitly pass it.  What is lifetime of 'this'?

Comment: @hmjd : I have updated it . at avakar : Thanks , will try that and get back . at all : Guys, i left an important thing . I freezed the http reconnect thread and the tcp reconnect thread worked fine . thats why am more interested to know the possible clashes between winsock & wininet .

Comment: @MartinJames : 'this' is class instance. it gets destroyed only on application exit/cleanup . so there is nothing to worry about scope of 'this' . Also i dont report a crash/exception .

Comment: Do one thing, just comment out the body of `MyThreadProc` other than the first and last lines and see what the `WaitForSingleObject(hSampleHandle, INFINITE);` returns and please tell that.

Comment: @rajraj : Tried it too , commented out the code in HTTP Reconnect Thread and it works fine . So it makes clear that some code resource is shared by winsock & wininet implementation that causes this behavior .

Comment: @AnanthaSubramaniam: OK, that sounds good. try this: Call `WaitForSingleObject(hHttpReq, sometime);` and if it return timeout, then call `CancelSynchronousIo(hHttpReq)` and then again `WaitForSingleObject(hHttpReq, sometime);`. Tell me what happens.

Comment: @rajraj : That isnt possible WaitForSingleObject isnt used for the MyHttpThread because what i have told you is just a prototype and i am not supposed to reveal the full code . My design doesnt handle Waiting on http request thread instead socket level timeouts are put . Anyways thanks for the CancelSynchronousIo Api . will learn about that .

Comment: @AnanthaSubramaniam: OK, told to try that just to find where it goes wrong. And i didn't asked to reveal the code. Anyway, try best. If you get any progress on this issue, post it so that we could know what went wrong. :)

Comment: @rajraj : sure , i dint really mean "you asked to reveal" . Will Update. Let me know if you or someone has succeeded with using winsock & wininet in the same app at same time . Thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: As mentioned in `CreateThread` documentation, use `_beginthreadex` instead `CreateThread` should be better.

Comment: @puttakhunchalee : The doc says "A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread management rather than CreateThread" . winsock or wininet isnt clearly a C run-time library i presume .

Comment: @AnanthaSubramaniam That is your thread routine, not winsock or wininet.

Answer (score 0):

So far seems to be a hang in Http Thread Implementation ( when run individually) where the Wininet dll loads causes the thread hang/freeze  .The question will be reopened if the hang in http is fixed and the similar behaviour is simulated .